# Getting permission-denied when trying to validate that Firestore user can only post comments under their own UID

Tags: angularjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have this code but don't really know where the insufficient  security error coming from. I can't seems to figure it out. Could it be from cloudfirestore?

```
postComment(getBlogId: string, comment: any): Promise<any> {
    if (this.currentUser) {
      return this.afs.collection('blogs').doc(getBlogId).collection('comments')
        .add({
          author: {
            '_id': this.currentUser.uid,
            'firstname': this.currentUser.displayName ? this.currentUser.displayName : this.currentUser.email
          },
          comment: comment.comment,
          createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          updatedAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
        });
    } else {
      return Promise.reject(new Error('LogIn to Continue!'));
    }
  }
```

This is in the services, but I am getting error when I submit a comment.
And in my component, when iI submit the console, it is giving me the form value and the value of the blog ID.

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.commentForm.value);
    console.log(this.blog._id);
    this.blogservices.postComment(this.blog._id, this.commentForm.value)
      .then(() => {
        this.blogservices.getComments(this.blog._id)
          .subscribe(comments => this.blog.comments = comments);
      });
  }
```

I can't really place it where I am getting the

> ERROR Error Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError [code=permission-denied]: Missing or insufficient permissions FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

And this is my firestore rules, which I think is correct because request should match user uid and the resouce attached to the data to be submitted.

```
 match /comments/{comment}{
      allow delete: if request.data.user_uid == request.auth.uid;
      allow write: if request.resource.data.user_uid == request.auth.uid;
      allow read;
    }
```

I have tried posting directly without the user info but getting same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're comparing the UID of the user posting (`request.auth.uid`), against `request.resource.data.user_uid`. That means that you'll need to have a field `user_uid` in the root of your document.

When adding the document however, you do it as this:

```
.add({
  author: {
    '_id': this.currentUser.uid,
    'firstname': this.currentUser.displayName ? this.currentUser.displayName : this.currentUser.email
  },
```

So the current user's UID is in `author._id`, which is a different path from what your security rules are looking at. The fix is to make sure both are using the same path. To do that in the security rules would look something like this:

```
allow write: if request.resource.data.author._id == request.auth.uid;
```

Comment: I changed the rules but still getting the same error. The author._id is coming from current logged in user.

Comment: For some reason it worked after breaking the app for like 3 times! I think there should is an issue with firestore. Anway thanks man